# What are the industry standard ways of packaging and deploying WCF services

Tags: wcf, service, setup-deployment

Is there a industry standard way of packaging and deploying web services which can cater to following contraints/Complexities

1. Web services are developed in different location and ultimately deployed on common site
2. This should take care of versioning ( Side by side web service deployment)
3. Client side versioning issues

Answer (score 0):

There are none.

Ok, "standards":

- UDDI for finding them.

otherwise have a look at http://servicesengine.codeplex.com/

This basically is a publishing front end for internal web services. So, you expose them all on one server / url (services.xxx.com) and basically can register them there, including versioning of different versions.

Comment: This sounds good for runtime management but how about creating a setup and installation process for wcf webservices

Comment: What for? I mean, seriously - this is exactly the solution you have for 1, 2 and 3: exposing a central maintaint front end. Push hthe services to a second website (internally) and forward calls.

One point of versioning is that it can not be done with side by side - .NET has no provision for that. A maintained front end system allows you to handle that transparently.